# Setting Environment Variables in Remote Bash Shells Spawned with SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, openssh

I often execute commands like this:

```
ssh username@hostname 'bash -s' < bashScriptToExecuteRemotely
```

I now have a case where `bashScriptToExecuteRemotely` is expecting certain environment variables to be set. In my case, let's say they are FOO=14 and BAR=giraffe.

How may I cause the bash shell that's launched on the remote host to have these environment variables set before executing `bashScriptToExecuteRemotely`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `env` command:

```
ssh username@hostname env VAR1=VALUE1 VAR2=VALUE thecommand the args
```

Answer (score 1):

This is tested to work. But I'm not certain if this is the way you want it.

```
ssh username@hostname 'FOO=14 BAR=giraffe bash -s' < script.sh
```